# I'm trying to install Plone 4.0 on a CentOS virtual machine with Python 2.6.6 but I'm getting an error when running buildout.cfg. Can anyone advise?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

```
$ python buildout.cfg -vvv

 File "buildout.cfg", line 2

  parts =
        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The following is the code where the error is occurring.

```
[buildout]

parts =
    productdistros
    instance
    zopepy
```

Anyone know how to fix the .cfg so that it runs without an error?

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you run buildout.  You'ld normally run

```
python bootstrap.py
bin/buildout -c buildout.cfg
```

Where `-c buildout.cfg` is not necessary as buildout.cfg is the default config file if none is given.

However, you are probably best setting things up with the unified installer.

See: http://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html